# how to print to screen only once in the end of a multiple for tests

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Well the header of this question isn't really clear but I can't [at this point of time] think of a better explanation than the real problem itself which is:
I have a method of a class let it be denoted as max_val[the name of the method not the class].
max_val run on the class does some calculates and return an  answer  between 1 to 100 (for my question it is not really important how and what this method does let's say she return this value randomly ).
max_val returns an int type.
In the main program I have

```
void main()
{
 bla bla some class defines;
 ....
 int max =0;
 for (int z = 1; z < 11; z++)
{
    for (int x = 1; x < 11; x++)
    {
        for (int c = 1; c < 11; c++)
        {
            for (int v = 1; v < 11; v++)
           {
               int check_m = max_val(z,x,c,v);
            ......

          }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

now instead of the 2nd .... what I want to do is to check if check_m > max then replace max=check, but
but I want at the end of all the fores (fores or fors?) to print to screen the max val and his matching configurations . notice that there might be more than one configuration for same global maximum max.
In case it isn't clear in configuration I mean what were the (z,x,c,v) that gave the maximum max.

I only thought about printing each time change occurs  "new max and new configuration ..." , or  when check+m == max " added configuration ..."
but OFC this is the easy solution .

I hope I made it clear enough .

Comment: This might be a valid use case for using `goto`. Otherwise use `break;` with the same condition at the end of each outer loop. If I understood you correctly: If you found `max`, you want to stop all the loops and print the value of `max` afterwards?

Comment: Nope , what I want is all the loops to run but at the end of them I want to print the value max and the configuration in which I got this max value .
here are 2 examples to a print I might get  :
#1:

[code]




     max value 33 . happend in : 1 | 2 | 3 | 4





#2



[code]




        max value 57. happend in : 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 ,, 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 ,, 9 | 9 | 9 | 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you loop through everything, keep track of both the current max and a list of all configurations that result in the current max. When you find a higher max, clear the list, add the new max's configuration, and continue.

In pseudocode,

```
max = 0
configurations = []

for ...
  for ...
    check_max = max_val(config)
    if (check_max > max) {
      // New max
      max = check_max
      configurations = [config]
    } else if (check_max == max) {
      // Another configuration for existing max
      configurations = configurations + [config]
    }

print configurations
```

Comment: yes this is what I thought /aimed for . 
but I had problems when tried to implemnet this.I went for an array of ints.first sized 4.     when check_max == max I need to create a new temp array copy the old value add the new value , delete the old config array and build a new bigger config array copy the value from temp and delete  temp. got a ton  bunch of errors right there ,so i thought maybe there is better way to do it maybe with string or something  I don't know of.

Comment: If your config variables are ints, you're on the right track with an array of 4 ints, but you want an array of arrays of 4 ints. To avoid managing its length yourself, check out [Vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).